# SQL Server 'FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY' Invalid usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, sql-fetch

I am trying to convert a Db2 query to SQL Server, I came across a construct I am not familiar with: FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY.

This is the query working on db2:

```
select * from products.series where state = 'xxx' order by id 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

and the error I am getting on SQL Server:

```
Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.
```

I have tried replacing FIRST with NEXT which seems to be admitted in SQL Server, but with no success.

I am using SQL Sever 2014

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with `OFFSET` clause

```
select * from products.series where state = 'xxx' order by id 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Just be aware that this syntax was introduced with SQL Server 2012, and cannot be used with earlier versions (like SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2).  Just a caveat for those reading along.  The "TOP" solution works with all versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Also note that "order by" is mandatory here. Trying to use offset and fetch without order by fails on SQL Server. SQL is probably the most portable query language around, but that really doesn't say much.

Answer (score 13):

use [**`top`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

```
select top 1 * from products.series where state = 'xxx' order by id
```

Comment: I imagine using TOP gives the same result but if possible I prefer to keep the syntax as similar as possible to the db2 query

Answer (score 2):

You can use top() function:

```
select top 1 * from table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (select * from products.series where state = 'xxx') as tmp ORDER BY id

Comment: Please always post some text to explain why it works

Answer (score -1):

QUESTION:  ELSE,
EXEC SQL
SELECT A.CDE_TRAN_REF
INTO   :DCLTACTV-BASE-INTRA.CDE-TRAN-REF
FROM
(SELECT CDE_TRAN_REF
FROM TACTV_BASE_INTRA
WHERE NUM_OFFICE = :WS-SELECT-NUM-OFFICE
AND
NUM_ACCT = :WS-SELECT-NUM-ACCT
AND
NUM_ACCT_TYPE = :WS-SELECT-NUM-ACCT-TYPE
AND
CDE_SRC_APPL_REF = :WS-SELECT-CDE-SRC-APPL-REF

```
               FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY (ERROR HERE SAYING 'SELECT NOT VALID)
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT CDE_TRAN_REF
                FROM TACTV_BASE_INTRA_TEMP
                WHERE NUM_OFFICE = :WS-SELECT_NUM_OFFICE   
                     AND
                      NUM_ACCT = :WS-SELECT-NUM-ACCT
                     AND
                      NUM_ACCT_TYPE = :WS-SELECT-NUM-ACCT-TYPE
                     AND
                      CDE_SRC_APPL_REF = :WS-SELECT-CDE-SRC-APPL-REF
                    ) AS A
                 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY (COMPILES WITH NO ERRORS)
                 WITH UR 
            END-EXEC
           END-IF
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).