# Select specific value from SQL table where column has same value for every record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I have a table where one column has the same value for every record.
I want to select this value from the database, which query is optimal?

```
SELECT DISTINCT RefID 
FROM Database.dbo.Table

SELECT TOP 1 RefID 
FROM Database.dbo.Table

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 RefId 
FROM Database.dbo.Table
```

Comment: Well, using a `TOP` clause **without** an accompanying `ORDER BY` is kinda useless, since you'll never know which `TOP 1` row you're getting - it will be arbitrary....

Comment: Seems like `SELECT RefID FROM Database.dbo.Table LIMIT 1` would be pretty efficient because it's very clear you only want one value from the table.

Comment: @marc_s I didn't include an `ORDER BY` because I don't need to know which `TOP 1` row I'm getting since every single row in that table has the same value for `RefID`.

Comment: @sj95126 Thank you but `LIMIT` is MySQL syntax. My query is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @jen: Right, overlooked the sql-server tag. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639157/13843268) has a 1-row equivalent for SQL Server.

Comment: Only `select top(1)` makes any sense here and only because you *know* all rows are identical so you only need to seek to the first row; Distinct will introduce a table scan either way, but you'd know this if you just examined the execution plan for each.

Comment: Adding `DISTINCT` is definitely less efficient here. But asking which is optimal doesn't make much sense, these three queries all do different things.

Answer (score 1):

The second query (with no DISTINCT) does the least work. But be sure to include a comment explaining exactly why you're doing it, because a TOP clause without an ORDER BY clause will be a red flag to anybody maintaining your code. You'll save them, and maybe your future self, a lot of time and trouble with that explanation.